# How to structure UVM RAL where Multiple interfaces on DUT have access to same set of registers in DUT (Ignore race conditions)

Tags: uvm

How to structure UVM RAL where Multiple interfaces on DUT have access to same set of registers in DUT (Ignore race conditions).

Both interfaces should see consistent information.
How will reg map work as they have 1 sequencer per reg map.
How will reg predictor work/get expected values.

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IimcC.png)

Answer (score -1):

When you hear "*register map*" think "*register interface*."

Each interface that can access a register block is a separate register map. For each interface you have, you'll need a separate register map. These interfaces can be completely different protocols.

Each map needs an adapter and a predictor*. Because the maps can address the registers with different base offsets, you'll want to call its `set_base_address()` function.

You can have as many maps and interfaces as you like, but **only one** of them will be considered the "default" map. When you call update, write, read, mirror, etc., and you do not specify a map, then this is the map/interface that will be driven.

Alternatively, you can specify a map to these calls and interact with the registers on a different interface.

**Technically, each *protocol* needs an adapter and predictor, but for the sake of simplicity you might keep them one to one.*

Comment: Could you please give snippet example? how does make multiple register map in soc ?